# When only secp384r1 is enabled in a server with TLS, 0-RTT doesn't work. Why?

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.3

0-RTT doesn't work when secp384r1 is the only one enabled in a server with TLS.

I am using OpenSSL:

- This happens in:

  - Apache with my own 0-RTT implementation (still in progress)
  - NGINX

If I add another curve to the list, like `secp384r1:prime256v1` or `secp384r1:X25519`: 0-RTT starts to work.

By *not working*, I mean, when I connect to the server using `s_client` in OpenSSL, it says that `Early data was rejected`, but if I enable another curve like the ones mentioned above: I get `Early data was accepted`.

I am unable to find about this anywhere online except this https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1969